# Is that possible to call for startActivity() from a static method?

Tags: android

I need to call for a `startActivity()` from one of my `static` method, is that possible somehow?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You'll need a context to be able to do that. Can you pass in a context into your static method as an argument?

```
public static void doSomething(Context ctx) {
    // do some stuff here
    ctx.startActivity(new Intent(ctx, OtherActivity.class));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this may also helps you

```
((Activity)mcontext).startActivity(new Intent(((Activity)mcontext),OtherActivity.class));
```