# Is it possible to abstract a startActivity call?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I was wondering if it's possible to abstract a startActivity call?  What I'm trying to do is abstract the following:

```
        Handler handler = new Handler(); 
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
         public void run() { 
             startActivity(nextIntent); 
         } 
    }, 2000);
```

Where I've previously setup the intent nextIntent with the proper class and the proper extras.  The idea is that I will be delaying the intent from starting for 2 seconds.  The above code works fine if I call it directly from my Activity.  What I'd like to do is abstract the above code so that I could call it from any activity like this:

```
DelayActivity.StartDelayedActivity(2,nextIntent);
```

This would start the next Activity nextIntent after a 2 second delay.  However, when I try to code this I get the following error:

```
The method startActivity(Intent) is undefined for the type new Runnable(){}
```

I've looked at topics like this: [Is that possible to call for startActivity() from a static method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12509968/is-that-possible-to-call-for-startactivity-from-a-static-method), but that thread defines the intent in the method.  I'd like to be able to take an intent that I've already setup and pass that.  Is what I'm looking for possible to do?  If so, what changes do I need to make?  Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a little dubious of what you're trying to achieve.  Do you really have enough activities that this is useful?  It sounds like you're trying to make a "pager" sort of service.  So why not just do that instead?

Additionally, you probably don't really want to create your own `Handler`, you probably just want to post that to the GUI thread of the Activity (really!).  So I'd reconsider your design.

But if you just want to disregard all of that, the answer to your immediate question is that you should pass a `Context` (such as a `this` from your `Activity` instance) on which you should call `startActivity`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. I'm new to Android development and am certainly open to redoing the design if it is more optimal. What I'm attempting to do is delay the start of an activity a specified amount of time. So the flow works like this. I have an Activity on the screen, the user takes some action and clicks a button which sends them to a new screen. This new screen is only up for a a few seconds at which point the app automatically starts up another activity.  The purpose is to show a temporary screen to the user, but not require any action from them to move off the temp screen

Comment: I'd stick with showing a dialog as pop up view, or a `ViewPager` to show a set of things in succession http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html.  Having a bunch of activities is a sign of code smell..

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the ViewPager idea.  My two concerns with that is it gives the user too much freedom to move back and forth between the screens, and it seems like it's built for handling the same objects on each screen (in the example there is a textbox on each screen).  In my app on screen has textboxes while another has buttons and a third has imageviews.  Using a ViewPager can I limit the navigation options the user has available and have different objects per screen?  Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: @NifflerX you're the programmer, you can control navigation as much as you want.  Personally I think your app should have as much navigation as possible (user's get upset when they can't go back, even if you think they shouldn't be able to).  But you can simply intercept the swipe events and make sure they can only go one way.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll look more into the ViewPager as opposed to multiple Activites.  But I'm worried I still run into the same issue where I want pages to progress automatically but with a timed delay.